# Optimising three.js for multiple elements/scenes with varying animations and colours

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm running a small web page where a few animated gradient blobs are positioned throughout the page, attached to existing elements, each with a slightly different colour and animation.

```
$(".blob").each(function(){     

    let scene = new THREE.Scene();  

    let lightTop = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, .7);
    lightTop.position.set(0, 500, 200);
    lightTop.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(lightTop);

    let lightBottom = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x000000, .95);
    lightBottom.position.set(0, -500, 400);
    lightBottom.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(lightBottom);

    let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x798296);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 1000);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        shininess: 100
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.8, 128, 128);  

    var speedSlider = $(this).data('speed'),
        spikesSlider = $(this).data('spikes'),
        processingSlider = $(this).data('processing'),
        color1 = $(this).data('color-1');
        color2 = $(this).data('color-2');   
        color3 = $(this).data('color-3');   
                    
    var $canvas = $(this).children('canvas'),
        canvas = $canvas[0],
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: canvas,
            context: canvas.getContext('webgl2'),
            antialias: false,
            alpha: false
        }),
        simplex = new SimplexNoise();

    renderer.setSize($canvas.width(), $canvas.height());
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 1 || 1);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    var rev = true;
    
    var color_parsed_1 = hexToRgb(color1);
    var color_parsed_2 = hexToRgb(color2);
    var color_parsed_3 = hexToRgb(color3);
    
    var cols = [{
      stop: 0,
      color: new THREE.Color(color_parsed_1)
    }, {
      stop: .55,
      color: new THREE.Color(color_parsed_2)
    }, {
      stop: 1,
      color: new THREE.Color(color_parsed_3)
    }];

    setGradient(geometry, cols, 'y', rev); 

    scene.add(sphere);

    var update = () => {

        var time = performance.now() * 0.00001 * speedSlider * Math.pow(processingSlider, 3),
            spikes = spikesSlider * processingSlider;

        for(var i = 0; i < sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
            var p = sphere.geometry.vertices[i];
            p.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.3 * simplex.noise3D(p.x * spikes, p.y * spikes, p.z * spikes + time));
        }

        sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        sphere.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
        sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    }
    
    function animate() {
        
        update();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 

});
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cdigitalig/Lqdr7825/18/

I'm guessing my approach is abysmal for performance - for each individual '.blob' element, a new canvas and scene are rendered, and the number of elements varies on page length. You'll also see a lot of variables, like the lighting, repeat unnecessarily for each '.blob' - but setting these before the .each loop results in no colours showing.

I'm struggling to keep all these individual blobs within one canvas, or within one scene - the positioning of blobs varies and so they have to render wherever the  element is currently on the page.

What would be the optimal solution here, performance-wise, and how do I make sure this entire layout is part of a single canvas/scene while maintaining different animations/colours per each blob?

Answer (score 0):

$(".blob").each(function(){

```
let scene = new THREE.Scene();  

let lightTop = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, .7);
lightTop.position.set(0, 500, 200);
lightTop.castShadow = true;
scene.add(lightTop);

let lightBottom = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x000000, .95);
lightBottom.position.set(0, -500, 400);
lightBottom.castShadow = true;
scene.add(lightBottom);

let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x798296);
scene.add(ambientLight);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 1000);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    shininess: 100
});

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.8, 128, 128);  

var speedSlider = $(this).data('speed'),
    spikesSlider = $(this).data('spikes'),
    processingSlider = $(this).data('processing'),
    color1 = $(this).data('color-1');
    color2 = $(this).data('color-2');   
    color3 = $(this).data('color-3');   
                
var $canvas = $(this).children('canvas'),
    canvas = $canvas[0],
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: canvas,
        context: canvas.getContext('webgl2'),
        antialias: false,
        alpha: false
    }),
    simplex = new SimplexNoise();

renderer.setSize($canvas.width(), $canvas.height());
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 1 || 1);

camera.position.z = 5;

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

var rev = true;

var color_parsed_1 = hexToRgb(color1);
var color_parsed_2 = hexToRgb(color2);
var color_parsed_3 = hexToRgb(color3);

var cols = [{
  stop: 0,
  color: new THREE.Color(color_parsed_1)
}, {
  stop: .55,
  color: new THREE.Color(color_parsed_2)
}, {
  stop: 1,
  color: new THREE.Color(color_parsed_3)
}];

setGradient(geometry, cols, 'y', rev); 

scene.add(sphere);

var update = () => {

    var time = performance.now() * 0.00001 * speedSlider * Math.pow(processingSlider, 3),
        spikes = spikesSlider * processingSlider;

    for(var i = 0; i < sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        var p = sphere.geometry.vertices[i];
        p.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.3 * simplex.noise3D(p.x * spikes, p.y * spikes, p.z * spikes + time));
    }

    sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    sphere.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}

function animate() {
    
    update();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

});

Comment: Can you clarify what's changed please? This is identical to what's in the .jsfiddle down to a letter...

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer..